Update CSP_NONCE value dynamically on each api request using Angular 16
Hello Angular Community,
I am working on implementing strict CSP (Content Security Policy) remediation in my Angular 16 application. Our server sends a nonce value in the CSP response header with each request. This nonce is used in place of unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval within the CSP header, formatted as nonce-dynamicnonce.
My challenge is to dynamically update the CSP_NONCE injection token with the new nonce value on each request. The official Angular documentation explains how to assign a nonce to CSP_NONCE during the bootstrapping phase, but I need guidance on how to update it dynamically for every request. If the CSP_NONCE is not updated with each request, the scripts will be blocked by the browser because the nonce in the response header will not match the current CSP_NONCE value.
Any advice or examples on how to achieve this dynamic update would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

The usual way of doing this is by adding server side rendering to the Angular application. In your case, using v16 it would be done using Angular Universal https://v16.angular.io/guide/universal The server you run via Node.js + Express will bootstrap Angular and render the URL for every request, hence you can configure every time a different CSP_NONCE. If using Apache, maybe you could run the server + a reverse proxy to let Angular Universal handle requests & responses and therefore inject the proper CSP NONCE.
